# Magmi Attribute Pricing

Tags: magento, csv, import, magmi

Iv spent the last few days building myself a golden product import CSV for Magmi, so far.. Wow! Such a powerful extension to use.

Iv hit a problem in which when trying to adjust the prices of associated products of a configurable product it only seems to work when there is no more than two simple products.

Iv been using this site:

https://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-configurable-item-processor/

About 2/3 of the way down is an area describing attribute pricing using the following code

```
color::blue:5.00;green:7.00
```

so I have converted this for my product which is a configurable product with 3 simple products, The first simple product uses the base price for the config product, then the 2 remaining simples need additional costs.

My products look like this:

6 pairs 50.00
12 pairs 90.00
24 pairs 160.00
config 50.00

my code to add additional costs to the two products not using the config price:

```
cquantity::12 pairs:40.00;24 pairs:110.00
```

when I import this I get no errors but it seems to apply the value wrong.

it applies the price 110.00 to the product option of 12 pairs an no additional cost to the 24 pair item.

If I use the following code on a configurable product with 2 simple products looking like so

6 pairs 50.00
12 pairs 90.00
config 50.00

```
cquantity::12 pairs:40.00
```

it correctly adds the price.

I have played around with swapping the semi-colon for a comma, as well as a "|" (bar) but nothing seems to correct my problem.

I am inserting this code in the csv column "super_attribute_pricing"

Has anybody else had this problem or know what could be causing this error?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same bug.

For example, I have the following value in my super_attribute_pricing field:

```
finish::Black:10;White:20
```

The Magmi manual says that it'll set the 'black' version of a product with a price of 10 and the 'white' one with a price of 20. But actually it assigns the price 20 to the 'black' and doesn't assign anything to 'white'.

I've debuugged magmi and looks like the sql code is formed correctly. But for some reason it just doesn't affect anything.

UPD: In the latest version of magmi the problem does not exist. Here's the related issue on github: https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/126